# PHP If statement always passing first statement

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm having a problem with this if statement, which sits inside of a wordpress loop. The first if statement — `if ( $caption == "1")` — seems to work, but the second seems to always pass, even when `$image_title` doesn't == those strings.

```
foreach ( $images as $attachment_id => $attachment ) {

        // $alt = get_post_meta($attachment->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
        $image_title = $attachment->post_title;
        $caption = $attachment->post_excerpt;
        $description = $attachment->post_content;

        $img_url = get_post_meta( $attachment->ID, '_gallery_link_url', true ); //WP Gallery Custom Links extra URL field


        if ( $caption == "1") { 

                echo '<div class="imagewrapb">';

                    if ($image_title == "Branding" or "Print" or "Digital" or"Packaging") {
                        echo '<h3>'.$image_title.'</h3>';
                        echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, '' );
                        echo '<a href="'.$img_url.'">'.'<div class="hover">'.$description.'</div>'.'</a>';

                    var_dump($image_title);

                    }

                    else if ($image_title == "Twitter") {
                        echo '<h3>'.$image_title.'</h3>';
                        echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, '' );
                        echo '<div class="twitterfeed"><h2>@V_IX</h2><ul id="twitter_update_list"><li>Twitter feed loading</li></ul></div>';
                    }                   

                    else if ($image_title == "Facebook") {
                        echo '<h3>'.$image_title.'</h3>';
                        echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, '' );
                        echo '<div class="facebookfeed">';
                        include 'facebook.php';
                        echo '</div>';
                    }

                    else {

                        if ( !empty($img_url) /*img_url exists*/ ){

                            echo '<h3>'.$image_title.'</h3>';

                            if ( !empty($description) /*description exists*/ ){
                                echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, '' );
                                echo '<a href="'.$img_url.'">'.'<div class="hover">'.$description.'</div>'.'</a>';
                            }

                            else {
                                echo '<a href="'.$img_url.'">';
                                echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, '' );
                                echo '</a>';

                            }
                        }   

                        else  { /*img_url doesnt exist*/

                            echo '<h3>'.$image_title.'</h3>';

                            if ( !empty($description) /*description exists*/ ){
                                echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, '' );
                                echo '<div class="hover">'.$description.'</div>';
                            }

                            else {
                                echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, '' );
                            }
                        }

                    }

                echo '</div>';


        }

        else {
                    echo '<div class="imagewrap">';

                    if ($image_title == "Branding" || "Print" || "Digital" || "Packaging") {
                        echo '<h3>'.$image_title.'</h3>';
                        echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, '' );
                        echo '<a href="'.$img_url.'">'.'<div class="hover">'.$description.'</div>'.'</a>';
                    }

                    else if ($image_title == "Twitter" ) {
                        echo '<h3>'.$image_title.'</h3>';
                        echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, '' );
                        echo '<div class="twitterfeed"><h2>@V_IX</h2><ul id="twitter_update_list"><li>Twitter feed loading</li></ul></div>';
                    }                   

                    else if ($image_title == "Facebook") {
                        echo '<h3>'.$image_title.'</h3>';
                        echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, '' );
                        echo '<div class="facebookfeed">';
                        include 'facebook.php';
                        echo '</div>';
                    }

                    else {

                        if ( !empty($img_url) /*img_url exists*/ ){

                            echo '<h3>'.$image_title.'</h3>';

                            if ( !empty($description) /*description exists*/ ){
                                echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, '' );
                                echo '<a href="'.$img_url.'">'.'<div class="hover">'.$description.'</div>'.'</a>';
                            }

                            else {
                                echo '<a href="'.$img_url.'">';
                                echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, '' );
                                echo '</a>';

                            }
                        }   

                        else  { /*img_url doesnt exist*/

                            echo '<h3>'.$image_title.'</h3>';

                            if ( !empty($description) /*description exists*/ ){
                                echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, '' );
                                echo '<div class="hover">'.$description.'</div>';
                            }

                            else {
                                echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, '' );
                            }
                        }

                    }

                echo '</div>';

        }
    }
```

Changing the if statement to (what I believe to be?) correct — `if (($image_title == "Branding")||($image_title == "Print")||($image_title == "Digital")||($image_title =="Packaging")) {`— seems to not display the variables with the 'branding' etc strings.

Comment: well if `$image_title` has the value of one of those 4, then it should work..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if ($image_title == "Branding" or "Print" or "Digital" or "Packaging")
```

must be:

```
if ($image_title == 'Branding' || $image_title == 'Print' || $image_title == 'Digital' || $image_title == 'Packaging')
```

Comment: And the reason is your actually saying if("Print"), and a non empty string will always be true.

Comment: In addition, if you must check if a value is one of a number of different values, you can use `in_array`, for example, `if (in_array($image_title, array('Branding', 'Print', 'Digital', 'Packaging'))) { }`